# Como flegar um checkbox via webbrowser?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Estou tentando marcar um checkbox via webbrowser, mas não estou conseguindo marcar.

```
HtmlElementCollection theElementCollection = default(HtmlElementCollection);
theElementCollection = doc.GetElementsByTagName("div");
foreach (HtmlElement curElement in theElementCollection)
{
    if (curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString() == "checkbox")
    {
        foreach (var item in curElement.All)
        {
            if (((HtmlElement)item).InnerText == null)
                continue;

            if (((HtmlElement)item).InnerText.Contains(" Windows 10") || ((HtmlElement)item).InnerText.Contains(" Windows XP")
                || ((HtmlElement)item).InnerText.Contains(" MS-DOS"))
            {
                ((HtmlElement)item).SetAttribute("checked", "true");
            }
        }
    }

    if (curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString() == "radio")
    {
        foreach (var item in curElement.All)
        {
            if (((HtmlElement)item).InnerText == null)
                continue;

            if (((HtmlElement)item).InnerText.Contains("Masculino"))
            {
                ((HtmlElement)item).SetAttribute("checked", "true");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando verifico o `html` da pagina ele esta setando o `label checked="true`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você está pegando o `HtmlElement` errado apenas

Comment: consegui corrigir com ((HtmlElement)item).FirstChild.SetAttribute("checked", "true");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como solicitado a solução ficou assim.

```
if (curElement.GetAttribute("className").ToString() == "checkbox")
    {
        foreach (var item in curElement.All)
        {
            if (((HtmlElement)item).InnerText == null)
                continue;

            if (((HtmlElement)item).InnerText.Contains(" Windows 10") || ((HtmlElement)item).InnerText.Contains(" Windows XP")
                || ((HtmlElement)item).InnerText.Contains(" MS-DOS"))
            {
                ((HtmlElement)item).FirstChild.SetAttribute("checked", "true");
            }
        }
    }
```

Bastou usar o `FirstChild`.